# Table , view , function or store procedure to get detail of oracle sqlstate and sqlerror detail

Tags: oracle, error-code

Is there any Oracle table, view , function or procedure or may be tool. For which sqlstate and/or sqlerror is input and it give detail of sqlstate and/or sqlerror. I can see sqlstate and sqlerror from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15817_01/appdev.111/b31228/appd.htm  but I want from oracle by sql. So it is more reliable :

Thanks in advance
Ram

Comment: how about oerr .. it is from oracle

Answer (score 1):

oerr - Oracle error messages, is a utility (script not an executable) which comes with unix and linux based oracle installations and can be found in the bin directory. Input to this script could be the error code.

this utility extracts error messages with suggested actions from the standard Oracle message files

Just because it uses awk functionalities, it is not supported in windows.

Usage details : 
http://www.oracledistilled.com/oracle-database/troubleshooting/using-the-oerr-utility-to-aid-in-error-investigation/l

`SQLERRM` and `SQLCODE` functions extract error messages and error codes, but it returns value only inside the exception handler and not in any SQLs, outside them, it always return success message! So, I doubt your requirement via SQL will be ever possible!